# Memory allocation of variable arrays in c

Tags: c

Is the memory to variable arrays allocated during run-time or compile-time in c?

```
int n; 
printf("Enter size of the array: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

int a[n];
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
      a[i] = 0;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just an (off-topic) note for you: this is not the standard in **C++** - you'd want to use a vector.

Answer (score 2):

Since the size `n` of the array is defined at runtime, then also the allocation happens in the runtime.

The memory is allocated from the stack, which is faster than allocating from the heap. But how much memory you can reserve is much lower.

Answer (score 1):

It is allocated on run time but on stack not on heap.